# Simplest expression for cos(1°) predating calculus

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, radicals, math-history

I was wondering what are the simplest formulas (or iterative process) to compute $\cos(1°)$ using only methods which predate calculus.

To give a more precise meaning to my question, let me just recap how to compute small values of $\cos$ and $\sin$. Basically you

1- either start from a known value (like $\sin 30° = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\cos 30° = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$). From this you can always compute the value for the half-angle (since $\cos 2 \alpha = 2 (\cos \alpha)^2 - 1$ one has that $\cos \tfrac{\beta}{2} = \sqrt{ \dfrac{\cos \beta +1}{2} }$.

2- or use two known values (in addition to the value for 15° one can obtain in the first step, on can use $\sin 18° = \tfrac{1}{4}(\sqrt{5}-1)$ and $\cos 18° = \sqrt{ \dfrac{ 5 + \sqrt{5}}{8}}$; one gets these values from the regular pentagon) and use the angle substraction formula $\cos 3° = \cos 15° \cos 18° + \sin 15° \sin 18°$.

These two tricks were historically used to get new values. But to get 1° one needs to "reverse" the formula for the triple angle $\cos 3 \alpha  = 4 (\cos \alpha)^3 - 3 \cos \alpha$. Since the solution of the cubic by radicals predate calculus, one gets a value for $\cos 1°$ which involves only radicals.

However, the formula depends a lot on the order in which the tricks were used (subtracting, bisecting and trisecting). For example, I get $\cos 3° =  \tfrac{1}{4} \sqrt{ 8 + \sqrt{15} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{ 10 - 2 \sqrt{5}} }$ or $\cos 3° =  \sqrt{ \dfrac{(5 + \sqrt{5})(2+\sqrt{3})}{32}}  + \tfrac{1}{8}(\sqrt{5} -1)(\sqrt{ 2 - \sqrt{3}})$. Although the formulas are "obviously" equal, they might not be equally hard to compute.

On the other there were other (iterative) methods known to compute $\cos 1°$ (a famous one is "Jost Bürgi's Kunstweg").

So what is the best formula or method to compute [numerically] the value of $\cos 1°$?

Comment: Nobody wants to know this unless they are willing to invoke irresolvable cube roots of complex numbers. The lowest we can practically go with whole-number degrees is actually $3°$.

Comment: Are you asking (as your title and `math-history` tag suggest) for the best result that had been achieved before the advent of Calculus? or are you asking (as your first line seems to suggest) for the best result that may have been devised since then but simply avoids invoking the tools of Calculus? ... If the former, then perhaps the dedicated [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for this question.

Comment: @OscarLanzi That's if we want an analytical formula. If we don't mind a numerical approximation, we can approximate $\cos 1^\circ$ pretty well.

Comment: @Blue well, it's actually a bit of both. I'm pretty sure that (historically) the first accurate computation of $\cos 1°$ was due to Jost Bürgi (beginning of 1600's). He did not use the solution to the cubic. Now there is a very narrow gap between the solution of the cubic and Jost Bürgi's Kunstweg (roughly 50 years). I doubt anyone took the trouble to do it some other way until calculus came around, but I don't know for sure. On the other hand I'd be delighted to hear other methods which could have been (like the one I sketched via the cubic) but didn't (or left no trace)

Comment: @ARG: Are you familiar with the [Madhava series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_series)?

Comment: @Blue no, I was not aware of this! The proof does seem to hinge a lot on ideas which are close to calculus. But on the other hand, the method of exhaustion (which is used for the volume of pyramids in Euclid's element and by Archimedes for the surface enclosed by a parabola) are also very close to calculus in spirit [and still are not considered as calculus by many]. As a last comment, the formula does seem to require a good value of $\pi$, so that I'm not sure how it would compare to the numerical evaluation of roots.